# Mysql select ok, update not working for same query

Tags: mysql

I have read many similar topics with almost identical title, but have not found a solution.

My problem is in mysql 5.7.35:

the following query returns 11129 results.

```
 SELECT * FROM `oc_product` WHERE `import_batch` IS NULL
```

when I try to update with :

```
UPDATE  oc_product
SET `import_batch` = 0
WHERE `import_batch` IS NULL
```

or

```
UPDATE  oc_product
SET `import_batch` = 'sometext'
WHERE `import_batch` IS NULL
```

the query affects 0 rows.

The import_batch column is  ***varchar(64)  utf8_general_ci***

```
  `import_batch` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL
   ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Are you setting the column to a value it already has? If the update results in no net change, it reports as zero rows affected.

Comment: nope, the value I want to set is other than null

Comment: do you receive any warnings or errors when attempting the update? are there any triggers or check constraints associated with the table?

Comment: no, nothing, I have tried many options. Only when import_batch column is NOT NULL (contains some string) can be updated with SET.

Comment: I am reading from other users about strict mode in mysql 5.7+ and problems in updating and inserting, but I dont know how to resolve. This is a simple query

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution, at least for me.

I created a php file and run the exact same query with

```
mysqli_query
```

Everything is ok this way!

@Shadow

Nope, the following PHP code did the trick, while via MySQL the same SQL code, that is:

```
UPDATE oc_product
SET oc_product.import_batch = 'bbbbbigbuy'
WHERE oc_product.isbn LIKE 'BB-%' 
  AND oc_product.import_batch IS NULL
```

did not.

The PHP code that worked:

```
   <?php 
   $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxxx");
   $conn->set_charset("utf8");
   $querrgggrry = "UPDATE oc_product
   SET oc_product.import_batch = 'bbbbbigbuy'
   WHERE oc_product.isbn LIKE 'BB-%' AND oc_product.import_batch IS NULL";
   mysqli_query($conn, $querrgggrry);
   mysqli_close($conn);
   ?>
```

Comment: Mysql is not affected by what programming language you run a query from. You probably made some other mistake with the update query.

Comment: nope. Exact same query via mysql (phpmyadmin) not working, when I created a php file with the same query worked.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that most likely you use phpmyadmin incorrectly. A lot less likely cause is a bug in phpmyadmin. Phpmyadmin uses mysqli under the hood and passes on sql statements to mysql just like you did in your code.

Comment: @Shadow Nope. I edited my answer to show the complete mysql query and the php code. I am not crazy, the mysql query in phpmyadmin was not working and the same query via php worked.

Comment: Then you must have done something wrong in phpmyadmin. If everything were the same, then the results cannot be different.

Answer (score 0):

Since the field is a varchar(64), make the 0 a '0' instead.

Comment: nope, still 0 affected rows. Same with any text in '...'

Comment: Do you need oc_product in quotes on the update query?

Comment: UPDATE  oc_product
     SET oc_product.import_batch = '0'
     WHERE oc_product.import_batch IS NULL has the same result, if this is what you mean.